# Making a Button Call a Phone Number in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, phone-call

I want to create a button that, when pressed, will call a phone number on the iPhone. I don't know if this is possible, but if it is I'd love for someone to help me with this.
I dont have any code for it, so someone would need to help me from start to finish.

Comment: @esqew close enough for me... why ppl cant search is beyond me

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try this out in your button action

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1115550123"]];
}
```

Then in Interface Builder you should connect the `TouchUpInside` event to the previously declared action (`callPhone:`) and you are done.

Comment: What kind of action should my action be though...

Comment: I'll update the answer for you.

Comment: @arclight And then, when the user finishes the call? the app doesn't return, when you finish the call the phone shows your contacts. how can I do for the app come back after the end of the call?

Comment: @GabrielMolter see other answer

Comment: this one works but it is wrong. it is tel:// - not tel:

Comment: For make call I need to add any native delegate?

Comment: P.S. Make sure there are no spaces in your number

Answer (score 38):

You can also go back to your original app when finish the call just by using this one instead:

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://2135554321"]];
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: For make call I need to add any native delegate?

Comment: @Yossi Is it possible to add here some custom message without using UIAlertView written by myself?

Comment: I don't think so, this is iOS default.

Comment: Is there anyway of calling multiple numbers with this?

Comment: What do you mean calling multiple numbers?

Comment: So for example, you can open ```MFMessageComposeViewController``` and send an email to more than one contact at once. So can you pass more than one phone number to the phone app and have a conference call?