# iOS Native iPhone Button for Calling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

I have an iPhone application and within the application, the user has can click a button which will make a phone call to a particular phone number.

Is there a built in icon or button or something like that which would work well or look good for this functionality? For making a phone call? Just something small.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a Button Call a Phone Number in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101286/making-a-button-call-a-phone-number-in-xcode)

Comment: @Josh This is not a duplicate of that question. This one is asking about the proper icon to use, not how to implement it.

Comment: @Marc: I don't read it that way at all, but okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/iphone-gui-psd/

And

http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/iphone-4-guid-psd-retina-display/

For the Retina Display

Comment: i'm not really sure what psd is?

Comment: Well psd is a Adobe PhotoShop file. but you just need to look for good looking png file or look at @Thomas Decaux library

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in the iOS SDK ;-( You should try this web site : http://www.cocoacontrols.com there is a small library to have cool buttons in pure objectif-c

Comment: Woow thats ...!! here is an UP for that.